# Fetching data from Google Translator API

Tags: c#, google-api, rapidapi

I used HttpWebRequest in c#, I got message "502 Bad Gateway"
that's my code, I think the problem is with the headers, But I Don't know What is it.

API link: https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1

```
string result = null;
string url = string.Format("https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com");
request.Headers.Add("x-rapidapi-key", "7c92b1508emsh36b05b0798008p18a939jsn602418a477ab");
```

I use the same header in JavaScript and works fine.

Comment: I don't know anything about this API, but are you sure you want that `x-rapidapi-key` displayed here?

Comment: If that's your real API key then now is the time to [invalidate it with the vendor and generate a new one](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys#api-key-rotation-or-resetting-a-compromised-api-key).

Comment: why not use the google cloud client libary https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet?

Answer (score 0):

`x-rapidapi-key` and `x-rapidapi-host` are custom headers. In order to add custom headers, you need to pass the name of header as an index something like this:

```
request.Headers["x-rapidapi-key"] = "*****************";
request.Headers["x-rapidapi-host"] = "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com";
```

P.S. You exposed your API key in the code snippet you posted above. It is not recommended due to security reasons. I recommend you to delete this API key and generate a new key from the [RapidAPI Developer Dashboard](https://rapidapi.com/developer/dashboard)